# change data before saving and change it after selecting to origin value in Django

Tags: django, forms

I have a class in Django:

```
class admin_new(CreateView):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'users/new.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users_index')
```

when user post data for example: "**2009-10 test**" , I wanna change and save it in db : "**10-2009 test**".

And when the user wants to edit it I need to change saved data again, means it should be convert to "**200-10 test**" in forms view.

example:

User entry: 2009-10 test

Save to db: 10-2009 test

Edit view: 2009-10 test

Save to db: 10-2009 test

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the data you could define a custom [`clean_<fieldname>` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) in your form, such as:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def clean_name(self):
        import re
        return re.sub(r'^(\d{4})-(\d{2})(.*)$', r'\2-\1\3', self.cleaned_data['name'])
```

To populate the values of your form in your UpdateView you can override the [`get_initial()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial):

```
def get_initial(self):
    import re
    initial = super(admin_edit, self).get_initial()
    p = get_object_or_404(self.model, **self.kwargs)
    initial.setdefault('name', re.sub(r'^(\d{4})-(\d{2})(.*)$', r'\2-\1\3', p.name))
    return initial
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Model Field for Datefield might do the job for you - see [Writing custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/).
Here is an example [CREATING A CUSTOM DJANGO DATETIMEFIELD MODEL](http://davidmburke.com/2010/09/07/creating-a-custom-django-datetimefield-model/)